# Installing Smart Switches

Tags: multiway-switch

I have been adding [Z-Wave Light Switch](http://www.leviton.com/en/products/DZS15-1LZZ-Wave) light switches to my house bit by bit.  For the most part, they haven't given me too much trouble.  Now I have come across a light that can be controlled in 3 different places.  Also one switch is at the bottom of the stairs on a 2-gang switch where one switch is on one breaker (downstairs lights) and the switch I am working on is on another breaker (upstairs lights).  All 3 locations have a neutral wire.

My first question, is does it matter that the gang box is on 2 circuits--particularly, is the neutral the same for both breakers?  Second, the  [instructions](http://www.leviton.com/en/docs/DI-000-DZS15-02A-W.PDF) say it matters where the switch goes, so how do I determine where each switch is in the sequence?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes?  Also, is it the downstairs light or the upstairs light that's on multi-way control?

Comment: No, the neutral is NOT the same for both breakers.  Each neutral must be rigorously kept with **its** hot.  You cannot steal a neutral from circuit 2 to power a smartswitch on circuit 1, no matter how much you may want to.

Comment: For what it's worth, I gave up and hired an electrician.  He thought he was coming in for a 10 minute job, but it took him 2 hours.